# Replacing initial Dataframe from an editable DataTable and using that new data frame in another table

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I have a nested DataTable in my Shiny app. Some of the columns in the child table are editable by the user. The goal here is to have the user edit the values and then the data frame would be replaced with those new values. Then I would like to take that replaced data frame and use it for another table. I need to use the edited values for calculations in the other table.

**workflow**:

```
create nested data table -> user edits values -> initial data is replaced by new data -> use the new data for another table
```

I've tried to use `reactiveValues()`, `dataTableProxy()`, `replaceData()` and `observeEvert()` to follow that workflow but have had no luck.

```
# Parent table
structure(list(Market = c("ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY"
), `Gross CPP` = c("$1.94", "$7.89"), `Gross CPM` = c("$1.02", 
"$0.82"), `Historical Composite Gross CPP (if applicable)` = c("$0", 
"$0"), `Historical Composite Gross CPM (if applicable)` = c("$0", 
"$0")), .Names = c("Market", "Gross CPP", "Gross CPM", "Historical Composite Gross CPP (if applicable)", 
"Historical Composite Gross CPM (if applicable)"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = "data.frame")

# Child table
structure(list(Market = c("ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", 
"ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", 
"ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", 
"ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ABILENE-SWEETWATER", 
"ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", 
"ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", 
"ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", 
"ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", 
"ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY", 
"ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY"), Daypart = c("Daytime", "Early Fringe", 
"Early Morning", "Early News", "Late Fringe", "Late News", "Prime Access", 
"Prime Time", "tv_2", "tv_3", "tv_cross_screen", "Daytime", "Early Fringe", 
"Early Morning", "Early News", "Late Fringe", "Late News", "Prime Access", 
"Prime Time", "tv_2", "tv_3", "tv_cross_screen"), `Mix (%)` = c(15, 
10, 15, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 15, 10, 15, 10, 5, 5, 10, 
10, 0, 0, 0), `Spot:30 (%)` = c(15, 10, 15, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 
0, 0, 0, 15, 10, 15, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0), `Spot:15 (%)` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), `Gross CPP ($)` = c(18, 18, 16, 23, 24, 40, 26, 44, 0, 0, 
0, 77, 71, 61, 78, 109, 145, 93, 213, 0, 0, 0), `Gross CPM ($)` = c(1.57, 
1.57, 1.39, 2, 2.09, 3.49, 2.27, 3.83, 23, 21, 13, 6.71, 6.19, 
5.32, 6.8, 9.5, 12.63, 8.1, 18.56, 23, 21, 13), `Historical Composite CPP ($)` = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), `Historical Composite CPM ($)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Market", 
"Daypart", "Mix (%)", "Spot:30 (%)", "Spot:15 (%)", "Gross CPP ($)", 
"Gross CPM ($)", "Historical Composite CPP ($)", "Historical Composite CPM ($)"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))

  # Module to create the nested structure of the table
  NestedData <- function(dat, children) {
    stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
    g <- function(d){
      if(is.data.frame(d)){
        purrr::transpose(d)
      }else{
        purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
      }
    }
    subdats <- lapply(children, g)
    oplus <- sapply(subdats, function(x) if(length(x)) "<img src=\'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/master/examples/resources/details_open.png\'/>" else "")
    cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }
  # Bind the market level and mix breakout data together for the final table
  market_mix_table <- reactive({
    # Take a dependency on input$goButton
    input$goButton
    isolate({
      # The rolled up market view - Parent table
      parent <- market_level_view()
      # The daypart breakout for each market - Child table
      child <- mix_breakout_digital_elements()
      # Make the dataframe
      # This must be met length(children) == nrow(dat)
      Dat <- NestedData(
        dat = parent,
        children = split(child, child$Market)
      )
      return(Dat)
    })
  })
  # Render the table
  output$daypartTable <- DT::renderDataTable({
    # Whether to show row names (set TRUE or FALSE)
    rowNames <- FALSE
    colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)
    # The data
    Dat <- market_mix_table()
    parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")
    excelTitle <- paste(
      input$name,
      input$medium,
      input$quarter,
      "Market CPM-CPP Breakout",
      sep=" "
    )
    ## If the JS stops working take the coed and put it here
    callback_js = JS(
      "var ok = true;",
      "function onUpdate(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {",
      "  var column = updatedCell.index().column;",
      "  if(column === 8){",
      "    ok = false;",
      "  }else if(column === 7){",
      "    ok = true;",
      "  }",
      "}",
      sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
      sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
      "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
      "for(var i=0; i < nrows; ++i){",
      "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
      "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
      "  }else{",
      "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().removeClass('details-control');",
      "  }",
      "}",
      "",
      "// make the table header of the nested table",
      "var format = function(d, childId){",
      "  if(d != null){",
      "    var html = ",
      "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
      "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + '\"><thead><tr>';",
      "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
      "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
      "    }",
      "    html += '</tr></thead><tfoot><tr>'",
      "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
      "      html += '<th></th>';",
      "    }",
      "    return html + '</tr></tfoot></table>';",
      "  } else {",
      "    return '';",
      "  }",
      "};",
      "",
      "// row callback to style the rows of the child tables",
      "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
      "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
      "    $(row).css('background-color', 'white');",
      "    $(row).hover(function(){",
      "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');",
      "    }, function() {",
      "      $(this).css('background-color', 'white');",
      "    });",
      "  } else {",
      "    $(row).css('background-color', 'white');",
      "    $(row).hover(function(){",
      "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lightblue');",
      "    }, function() {",
      "      $(this).css('background-color', 'white');",
      "    });",
      "  }",
      "};",
      "",
      "// header callback to style the header of the child tables",
      "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
      "  $('th', thead).css({",
      "    'color': 'black',",
      "    'background-color': 'white'",
      "  });",
      "};",
      "",
      "// make the datatable",
      "var format_datatable = function(d, childId, rowIdx){",
      "  // footer callback to display the totals",
      "  // and update the parent row",
      "  var footerCallback = function(tfoot, data, start, end, display){",
      "    $('th', tfoot).css('background-color', '#F5F2F2');",
      "    var api = this.api();",
      "// update the Override CPM when the Override CPP is changed",
      "    var col_override_cpp = api.column(7).data();",
      "    var col_population = api.column(9).data();",
      "    if(ok){",
      "      for(var i = 0; i < col_override_cpp.length; i++){",
      "        api.cell(i,8).data(((parseFloat(col_override_cpp[i])*100)/(parseFloat(col_population[i])/1000)).toFixed(2));",
      "      }",
      "    }",
      "// update the Override CPP when the Override CPM is changed",
      "    var col_override_cpm = api.column(8).data();",
      "    for(var i = 0; i < col_override_cpm.length; i++){",
      "      api.cell(i,7).data(((parseFloat(col_override_cpm[i])*parseFloat(col_population[i])/1000)/100).toFixed(0));",
      "    }",
      "// Update the spot mixes",
      "    var col_mix_percentage = api.column(2).data();",
      "    var col_mix60_mix30 = api.column(10).data();",
      "    var col_mix30_mix15 = api.column(11).data();",
      "    for(var i = 0; i < col_mix_percentage.length; i++){",
      "      api.cell(i,3).data((parseFloat(col_mix_percentage[i])*parseFloat(col_mix60_mix30[i])).toFixed(1));",
      "      api.cell(i,4).data((parseFloat(col_mix_percentage[i])*parseFloat(col_mix30_mix15[i])).toFixed(1));",
      "    }",
      "    var child_col_CPM = api.column(6).data();",
      "    for(var i = 0; i < child_col_CPM.length; i++){",
      "      api.cell(i,6).data(parseFloat(child_col_CPM[i]).toFixed(2));",
      "    }",
      # "    parseFloat(api.column(5)).toFixed(2)",
      "// Make the footer sums",
      "    api.columns().eq(0).each(function(index){",
      "      if(index == 0) return $(api.column(index).footer()).html('Mix Total');",
      "      var coldata = api.column(index).data();",
      "      var total = coldata",
      "          .reduce(function(a, b){return parseInt(a) + parseInt(b)}, 0);",
      "      if(index == 3 || index == 4 ||index == 5 || index == 6 || index == 7 || index == 8) {",
      "        $(api.column(index).footer()).html('');",
      "      } else {",
      "        $(api.column(index).footer()).html(total);",
      "      }",
      "      if(total == 100) {",
      "        $(api.column(index).footer()).css({'color': 'green'});",
      "      } else {",
      "        $(api.column(index).footer()).css({'color': 'red'});",
      "      }",
      "    })",
      "  // update the parent row",
      "    var col_share = api.column(2).data();",
      "    var col_CPP = api.column(5).data();",
      "    var col_CPM = api.column(6).data();",
      "    var col_Historical_CPP = api.column(7).data();",
      "    var col_Historical_CPM = api.column(8).data();",
      "    var CPP = 0, CPM = 0, Historical_CPP = 0, Historical_CPM = 0;",
      "    for(var i = 0; i < col_share.length; i++){",
      "      CPP += (parseInt(col_share[i])*parseInt(col_CPP[i]).toFixed(0));",
      "      CPM += (parseInt(col_share[i])*parseInt(col_CPM[i]).toFixed(2));",
      "      Historical_CPP += (parseInt(col_share[i])*parseInt(col_Historical_CPP[i]).toFixed(0));",
      "      Historical_CPM += (parseInt(col_share[i])*parseInt(col_Historical_CPM[i]).toFixed(2));",
      "    }",
      "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+3).data((CPP/100).toFixed(2));",
      "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+4).data((CPM/100).toFixed(2));",
      "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+5).data((Historical_CPP/100).toFixed(2));",
      "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+6).data((Historical_CPM/100).toFixed(2));",
      "  }",
      "  var n = d.length - 1;",
      "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
      "  var columns = Object.keys(d[n][0]).map(function(x){",
      "    return {data: x, title: x};",
      "  });",
      "  if (Object.keys(d[n][0]).indexOf('_details') === -1) {",
      "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
      "                 'data': d[n],",
      "                 'columns': columns,",
      "                 'autoWidth': true,",
      "                 'deferRender': true,",
      "                 'info': false,",
      "                 'lengthChange': false,",
      "                 'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
      "                 'order': [],",
      "                 'paging': true,",
      "                 'scrollX': false,",
      "                 'scrollY': false,",
      "                 'searching': false,",
      "                 'sortClasses': false,",
      "                 'pageLength': 50,",
      "                 'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
      "                 'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
      "                 'footerCallback': footerCallback,",
      "                 'columnDefs': [",
      "                  {targets: [0, 9, 10, 11], visible: false},",
      "                  {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
      "                 ]",
      "               });",
      "  } else {",
      "    var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
      "            'data': d[n],",
      "            'columns': columns,",
      "            'autoWidth': true,",
      "            'deferRender': true,",
      "            'info': false,",
      "            'lengthChange': false,",
      "            'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
      "            'order': [],",
      "            'paging': true,",
      "            'scrollX': false,",
      "            'scrollY': false,",
      "            'searching': false,",
      "            'sortClasses': false,",
      "            'pageLength': 50,",
      "            'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
      "            'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
      "            'footerCallback': footerCallback,",
      "            'columnDefs': [",
      "              {targets: [0, 9, 10, 11], visible: false},",
      "              {targets: -1, visible: false},",
      "              {targets: 0, orderable: false, className: 'details-control'},",
      "              {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
      "             ]",
      "          }).column(0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
      "  }",
      "  subtable.MakeCellsEditable({",
      "    onUpdate: onUpdate,",
      "    inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
      "    columns: [2, 7, 8],",
      "    confirmationButton: {",
      "      confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
      "      cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
      "    }",
      "  });",
      "};",
      "",
      "// display the child table on click",
      "// array to store the id's of the already created child tables",
      "var children = [];",
      "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
      "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
      "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
      "      td = $(this),",
      "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
      "      rowIdx = row.index();",
      "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
      "    row.child.hide();",
      "    td.html('<img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/master/examples/resources/details_open.png\"/>');",
      "  } else {",
      "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
      "// this child table has not been created yet",
      "    if(children.indexOf(childId) === -1){",
      "      children.push(childId);",
      "      row.child(format(row.data(), childId)).show();",
      "    td.html('<img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/master/examples/resources/details_close.png\"/>');",
      "      format_datatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
      "    }else{",
      "      row.child(true);",
      "    td.html('<img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/master/examples/resources/details_close.png\"/>');",
      "    }",
      "  }",
      "});"
    )
    # Download button
    downloadButtonJS <-  c(
      "function(xlsx) {",
      "  var table = $('#daypartTable').find('table').DataTable();",
      "  // Letters for Excel columns.",
      "  var LETTERS = [",
      "    'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M',",
      "    'N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'",
      "  ];",
      "  // Get sheet.",
      "  var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];",
      "  // Get a clone of the sheet data.        ",
      "  var sheetData = $('sheetData', sheet).clone();",
      "  // Clear the current sheet data for appending rows.",
      "  $('sheetData', sheet).empty();",
      "  // Row count in Excel sheet.",
      "  var rowCount = 1;",
      "  // Iterate each row in the sheet data.",
      "  $(sheetData).children().each(function (index) {",
      "    // Used for DT row() API to get child data.",
      "    var rowIndex = index - 2;", #
      "    // Don't process row if its the header row.",
      sprintf("    if (index > 1 && index < %d) {", nrow(Dat)+2), #
      "      // Get row",
      "      var row = $(this.outerHTML);",
      "      // Set the Excel row attr to the current Excel row count.",
      "      row.attr('r', rowCount);",
      "      // Iterate each cell in the row to change the row number.",
      "      row.children().each(function (index) {",
      "        var cell = $(this);",
      "        // Set each cell's row value.",
      "        var rc = cell.attr('r');",
      "        rc = rc.replace(/\\d+$/, \"\") + rowCount;",
      "        cell.attr('r', rc);",
      "      });",
      "      // Get the row HTML and append to sheetData.",
      "      row = row[0].outerHTML;",
      "      $('sheetData', sheet).append(row);",
      "      rowCount++;",
      "      // Get the child data - could be any data attached to the row.",
      "      // Basically this grabd all the rows of data",
      sprintf("      var childData = table.row(':eq(' + rowIndex + ')').data()[%d];", ncol(Dat)-1),
      "      if (childData.length > 0) {",
      "        var colNames = Object.keys(childData[0]).slice(1,9);",
      "        // Prepare Excel formatted row",
      "        headerRow = '<row r=\"' + rowCount +",
      "          '\"><c t=\"inlineStr\" r=\"A' + rowCount +",
      "          '\"><is><t></t></is></c>';",
      "        for(var i = 0; i < colNames.length; i++){",
      "          headerRow = headerRow +",
      "            '<c t=\"inlineStr\" r=\"' + LETTERS[i+1] + rowCount +",
      "            '\" s=\"7\"><is><t>' + colNames[i] +", 
      "            '</t></is></c>';",
      "        }",
      "        headerRow = headerRow + '</row>';",
      "        // Append header row to sheetData.",
      "        $('sheetData', sheet).append(headerRow);",
      "        rowCount++; // Inc excelt row counter.",
      "      }",
      "      // The child data is an array of rows",
      "      for (let c = 0; c < childData.length; c++) {",
      "        // Get row data.",
      "        var child = childData[c];",
      "        // Prepare Excel formatted row",
      "        var childRow = '<row r=\"' + rowCount +",
      "          '\"><c t=\"inlineStr\" r=\"A' + rowCount +",
      "          '\"><is><t></t></is></c>';",
      "        for(let i = 0; i < colNames.length; i++){",
      "          childRow = childRow +",
      "            '<c t=\"inlineStr\" r=\"' + LETTERS[i+1] + rowCount +",
      "            '\" s=\"5\"><is><t>' + child[colNames[i]] +", 
      "            '</t></is></c>';",
      "        }",
      "        childRow = childRow + '</row>';",
      "        // Append row to sheetData.",
      "        $('sheetData', sheet).append(childRow);",
      "        rowCount++; // Inc excel row counter.",
      "      }",
      "      // Just append the header row and increment the excel row counter.",
      "    } else {",
      "      $('sheetData', sheet).append(this.outerHTML);",
      "      rowCount++;",
      "    }",
      "  });",
      "}"
    )
    # Table
    table <- DT::datatable(
      Dat,
      callback = callback_js,
      rownames = rowNames,
      escape = -colIdx-1,
      style = "bootstrap4",
      extensions = 'Buttons',
      options = list(
        dom = "Bt",
        columnDefs = list(
          list(width = '30px', targets = 0),
          list(width = '330px', targets = 1),
          list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx),
          list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = colIdx),
          list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
        ),
        buttons = list(
          list(
            extend = "excel",
            className = 'btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt',
            text = " Export",
            exportOptions = list(
              orthogonal = "export",
              columns = 0:(ncol(Dat)-2)
            ),
            title = excelTitle,
            orientation = "landscape",
            customize = JS(downloadButtonJS)
          )
        ),
        lengthMenu = list(c(-1, 10, 20),
                          c("All", 10, 20))
      )
    )
    # Call the html tools deps (js & css files in this directory)
    cell_edit_dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
      "CellEdit", "1.0.19", 
      src = 'www/',
      script = "dataTables.cellEdit.js",
      stylesheet = "dataTables.cellEdit.css"
    )
    table$dependencies <- c(table$dependencies, list(cell_edit_dep))
    
    table %>% formatStyle(
      c(MARKET[2], 'Population', SQAD_CPP_DOLLAR, SQAD_CPM_DOLLAR, OVERRIDE_CPP_DOLLAR, OVERRIDE_CPM_DOLLAR),
      target = 'row',
      backgroundColor = "#F5F2F2"
    )
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  ### This is where I am trying to save the edits to the table and
  ### use those new values for the below table 
  output$market_costings_gross_net_table <- renderTable({
    # Get the data from reative function
    market_costings <- market_level_view()
    reactive_market_costings <- reactiveValues(data = market_costings)
    
    proxy <- dataTableProxy("daypartTable")
    
    observeEvent(input$tableRefresh, {
      DT::replaceData(proxy, reactive_market_costings$data)
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First round

To get the data in Shiny:

- add this line at the end of the `footerCallback` function:

  ```
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('data:nestedData', table.data().toArray());",
  ```
- before the Shiny app, add:

```r
  library(jsonlite)

  registerInputHandler(
    "nestedData", 
    function(data, ...){
      fromJSON(toJSON(data))
    },
    force = TRUE
  )
```

- then the data is available in `input[["data"]]`:

```r
  observe({
    print(input[["data"]])
  })
```

If you need more help, please edit your post to make your code reproducible. I don't have your latest version of this code.

---

### Second round

As said in my comment, it's better to use `toFixed` in a `render` option. I also set the type of editable cells to `number`, so that the values of the edited cells are not converted to strings, and moreover there are spinner arrows in the editing boxes.

```r
library(DT)

df_children <-
  structure(
    list(
      Market = c(
        "ABILENE-SWEETWATER",
        "ABILENE-SWEETWATER",
        "ABILENE-SWEETWATER",
        "ABILENE-SWEETWATER",
        "ABILENE-SWEETWATER",
        "ABILENE-SWEETWATER",
        "ABILENE-SWEETWATER",
        "ABILENE-SWEETWATER",
        "ABILENE-SWEETWATER",
        "ABILENE-SWEETWATER",
        "ABILENE-SWEETWATER",
        "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY",
        "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY",
        "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY",
        "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY",
        "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY",
        "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY",
        "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY",
        "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY",
        "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY",
        "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY",
        "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY"
      ),
      Daypart = c(
        "Daytime",
        "Early Fringe",
        "Early Morning",
        "Early News",
        "Late Fringe",
        "Late News",
        "Prime Access",
        "Prime Time",
        "tv_2",
        "tv_3",
        "tv_cross_screen",
        "Daytime",
        "Early Fringe",
        "Early Morning",
        "Early News",
        "Late Fringe",
        "Late News",
        "Prime Access",
        "Prime Time",
        "tv_2",
        "tv_3",
        "tv_cross_screen"
      ),
      `Mix (%)` = c(15,
                    10, 15, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 15, 10, 15, 10, 5, 5, 10,
                    10, 0, 0, 0),
      `Spot:30 (%)` = c(15, 10, 15, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10,
                        0, 0, 0, 15, 10, 15, 10, 5, 5, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0),
      `Spot:15 (%)` = c(0,
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
      `Gross CPP ($)` = c(
        18,
        18,
        16,
        23,
        24,
        40,
        26,
        44,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        77,
        71,
        61,
        78,
        109,
        145,
        93,
        213,
        0,
        0,
        0
      ),
      `Gross CPM ($)` = c(
        1.57,
        1.57,
        1.39,
        2,
        2.09,
        3.49,
        2.27,
        3.83,
        23,
        21,
        13,
        6.71,
        6.19,
        5.32,
        6.8,
        9.5,
        12.63,
        8.1,
        18.56,
        23,
        21,
        13
      ),
      `Historical Composite CPP ($)` = c(0,
                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
      `Historical Composite CPM ($)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                         0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
      population = c(
        47200L,
        47200L,
        47200L,
        47200L,
        47200L,
        47200L,
        47200L,
        47200L,
        47200L,
        162700L,
        162700L,
        162700L,
        162700L,
        162700L,
        162700L,
        162700L,
        162700L,
        162700L,
        162700L,
        162700L,
        162700L,
        162700L
      ),
      slider_60s = c(
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4,
        0.4
      ),
      slider_30s = c(
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6,
        0.6
      )
    ),
    .Names = c(
      "Market",
      "Daypart",
      "Mix (%)",
      "Spot:30 (%)",
      "Spot:15 (%)",
      "Gross CPP ($)",
      "Gross CPM ($)",
      "Historical Composite CPP ($)",
      "Historical Composite CPM ($)",
      "population",
      "slider_60s",
      "slider_30s"
    ),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA,-22L)
  )

df_parent <-
  structure(
    list(
      Market = c("ABILENE-SWEETWATER", "ALBANY-SCHENECTADY-TROY, NY"),
      `Gross CPP` = c(1.94, 7.89),
      `Gross CPM` = c(1.02, 0.82),
      `Historical Composite Gross CPP (if applicable)` = c(0, 0),
      `Historical Composite Gross CPM (if applicable)` = c(0, 0)
    ),
    .Names = c(
      "Market",
      "Gross CPP",
      "Gross CPM",
      "Historical Composite Gross CPP (if applicable)",
      "Historical Composite Gross CPM (if applicable)"
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-2L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )

# function to make the required dataframe
NestedData <- function(dat, children){
  stopifnot(length(children) == nrow(dat))
  g <- function(d){
    if(is.data.frame(d)){
      purrr::transpose(d)
    }else{
      purrr::transpose(NestedData(d[[1]], children = d$children))
    }
  }
  subdats <- lapply(children, g)
  oplus <- sapply(subdats, function(x) if(length(x)) "&oplus;" else "")
  cbind(" " = oplus, dat, "_details" = I(subdats), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

# make the required dataframe
# one must have: length(children) == nrow(dat)
Dat <- NestedData(
  dat = df_parent,
  children = split(df_children, df_children$Market)
)

## whether to show row names (set TRUE or FALSE)
rowNames <- FALSE
colIdx <- as.integer(rowNames)

## make the callback
parentRows <- which(Dat[,1] != "")

callback_js = JS(
  "var ok = true;",
  "function onUpdate(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {",
  "  var column = updatedCell.index().column;",
  "  if(column === 8){",
  "    ok = false;",
  "  }else if(column === 7){",
  "    ok = true;",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "function render0(data, type, row) {", # @Timothy, new
  "  if(type === 'display') {",
  "    return parseFloat(data).toFixed(0);",
  "  } else {",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "function render2(data, type, row) {", # @Timothy, new
  "  if(type === 'display') {",
  "    return parseFloat(data).toFixed(2);",
  "  } else {",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}",
  sprintf("var parentRows = [%s];", toString(parentRows-1)),
  sprintf("var j0 = %d;", colIdx),
  "var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "for(var i=0; i < nrows; ++i){",
  "  if(parentRows.indexOf(i) > -1){",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});",
  "  }else{",
  "    table.cell(i,j0).nodes().to$().removeClass('details-control');",
  "  }",
  "}",
  "",
  "// make the table header of the nested table",
  "var format = function(d, childId){",
  "  if(d != null){",
  "    var html = ",
  "      '<table class=\"display compact hover\" ' + ",
  "      'style=\"padding-left: 30px;\" id=\"' + childId + '\"><thead><tr>';",
  "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
  "      html += '<th>' + key + '</th>';",
  "    }",
  "    html += '</tr></thead><tfoot><tr>'",
  "    for(var key in d[d.length-1][0]){",
  "      html += '<th></th>';",
  "    }",
  "    return html + '</tr></tfoot></table>';",
  "  } else {",
  "    return '';",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// row callback to style the rows of the child tables",
  "var rowCallback = function(row, dat, displayNum, index){",
  "  if($(row).hasClass('odd')){",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lightgreen');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    });",
  "  } else {",
  "    $(row).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    $(row).hover(function(){",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'lightblue');",
  "    }, function() {",
  "      $(this).css('background-color', 'white');",
  "    });",
  "  }",
  "};",
  "",
  "// header callback to style the header of the child tables",
  "var headerCallback = function(thead, data, start, end, display){",
  "  $('th', thead).css({",
  "    'color': 'black',",
  "    'background-color': 'white'",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// make the datatable",
  "var format_datatable = function(d, childId, rowIdx){",
  "  // footer callback to display the totals",
  "  // and update the parent row",
  "  var footerCallback = function(tfoot, data, start, end, display){", # @Timothy, I removed all the 'toFixed'
  "    $('th', tfoot).css('background-color', '#F5F2F2');",
  "    var api = this.api();",
  "// update the Override CPM when the Override CPP is changed",
  "    var col_override_cpp = api.column(7).data();",
  "    var col_population = api.column(9).data();",
  "    if(ok){",
  "      for(var i = 0; i < col_override_cpp.length; i++){",
  "        api.cell(i,8).data(((parseFloat(col_override_cpp[i])*100)/(parseFloat(col_population[i])/1000)));",
  "      }",
  "    }",
  "// update the Override CPP when the Override CPM is changed",
  "    var col_override_cpm = api.column(8).data();",
  "    for(var i = 0; i < col_override_cpm.length; i++){",
  "      api.cell(i,7).data(((parseFloat(col_override_cpm[i])*parseFloat(col_population[i])/1000)/100));",
  "    }",
  "// Update the spot mixes",
  "    var col_mix_percentage = api.column(2).data();",
  "    var col_mix60_mix30 = api.column(10).data();",
  "    var col_mix30_mix15 = api.column(11).data();",
  "    for(var i = 0; i < col_mix_percentage.length; i++){",
  "      api.cell(i,3).data((parseFloat(col_mix_percentage[i])*parseFloat(col_mix60_mix30[i])));",
  "      api.cell(i,4).data((parseFloat(col_mix_percentage[i])*parseFloat(col_mix30_mix15[i])));",
  "    }",
  "    var child_col_CPM = api.column(6).data();",
  "    for(var i = 0; i < child_col_CPM.length; i++){",
  "      api.cell(i,6).data(parseFloat(child_col_CPM[i]));",
  "    }",
  "// Make the footer sums",
  "    api.columns().eq(0).each(function(index){",
  "      if(index == 0) return $(api.column(index).footer()).html('Mix Total');",
  "      var coldata = api.column(index).data();",
  "      var total = coldata",
  "          .reduce(function(a, b){return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b);}, 0);",
  "      if(index == 3 || index == 4 ||index == 5 || index == 6 || index == 7 || index == 8) {",
  "        $(api.column(index).footer()).html('');",
  "      } else {",
  "        $(api.column(index).footer()).html(total);",
  "      }",
  "      if(total == 100) {",
  "        $(api.column(index).footer()).css({'color': 'green'});",
  "      } else {",
  "        $(api.column(index).footer()).css({'color': 'red'});",
  "      }",
  "    })",
  "  // update the parent row", # @Timothy, I replaced everywhere parseInt with parseFloat
  "    var col_share = api.column(2).data();",
  "    var col_CPP = api.column(5).data();",
  "    var col_CPM = api.column(6).data();",
  "    var col_Historical_CPP = api.column(7).data();",
  "    var col_Historical_CPM = api.column(8).data();",
  "    var CPP = 0, CPM = 0, Historical_CPP = 0, Historical_CPM = 0;",
  "    for(var i = 0; i < col_share.length; i++){",
  "      CPP += (parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_CPP[i]));",
  "      CPM += (parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_CPM[i]));",
  "      Historical_CPP += (parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_Historical_CPP[i]));",
  "      Historical_CPM += (parseFloat(col_share[i])*parseFloat(col_Historical_CPM[i]));",
  "    }",
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+2).data(CPP/100);", # @Timothy, there were errors here (it's j0 + 2/3/4/5)
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+3).data(CPM/100);",
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+4).data(Historical_CPP/100);",
  "    table.cell(rowIdx, j0+5).data(Historical_CPM/100);",
  "    Shiny.setInputValue('data:nestedData', table.data().toArray());",
  "  }",
  "  var n = d.length - 1;",
  "  var id = 'table#' + childId;",
  "  var columns = Object.keys(d[n][0]).map(function(x){",
  "    return {data: x, title: x};",
  "  });",
  "  var subtable = $(id).DataTable({",
  "                 'data': d[n],",
  "                 'columns': columns,",
  "                 'autoWidth': true,",
  "                 'deferRender': true,",
  "                 'info': false,",
  "                 'lengthChange': false,",
  "                 'ordering': d[n].length > 1,",
  "                 'order': [],",
  "                 'paging': true,",
  "                 'scrollX': false,",
  "                 'scrollY': false,",
  "                 'searching': false,",
  "                 'sortClasses': false,",
  "                 'pageLength': 50,",
  "                 'rowCallback': rowCallback,",
  "                 'headerCallback': headerCallback,",
  "                 'footerCallback': footerCallback,",
  "                 'columnDefs': [",
  "                  {targets: [2, 3, 4], render: render0},", # @Timothy, new
  "                  {targets: [5, 6, 7, 8], render: render2},", # @Timothy, new
  "                  {targets: [0, 9, 10, 11], visible: false},",
  "                  {targets: '_all', className: 'dt-center'}",
  "                 ]",
  "               });",
  "  subtable.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "    onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "    inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "    columns: [2, 7, 8],", 
  "    inputTypes: [", # @Timothy, new 
  "      {column: 2, type: 'number'},",
  "      {column: 7, type: 'number'},",
  "      {column: 8, type: 'number'}",
  "    ],",
  "    confirmationButton: {",
  "      confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "      cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "    }",
  "  });",
  "};",
  "",
  "// display the child table on click",
  "// array to store the id's of the already created child tables",
  "var children = [];",
  "table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function(){",
  "  var tbl = $(this).closest('table'),",
  "      tblId = tbl.attr('id'),",
  "      td = $(this),",
  "      row = $(tbl).DataTable().row(td.closest('tr')),",
  "      rowIdx = row.index();",
  "  if(row.child.isShown()){",
  "    row.child.hide();",
  "    td.html('<img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/master/examples/resources/details_open.png\"/>');",
  "  } else {",
  "    var childId = tblId + '-child-' + rowIdx;",
  "// this child table has not been created yet",
  "    if(children.indexOf(childId) === -1){",
  "      children.push(childId);",
  "      row.child(format(row.data(), childId)).show();",
  "    td.html('<img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/master/examples/resources/details_close.png\"/>');",
  "      format_datatable(row.data(), childId, rowIdx);",
  "    }else{",
  "      row.child(true);",
  "    td.html('<img src=\"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/master/examples/resources/details_close.png\"/>');",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});"
)


render_js <- JS( # @Timothy, new
  "function(data, type, row) {",
  "  if(type === 'display') {",
  "    return '$' + data.toFixed(2);",
  "  } else {",
  "    return data;",
  "  }",
  "}"
)


## the datatable
dtable <- datatable(
  Dat, callback = callback_js, rownames = rowNames, escape = -colIdx-1, 
  extensions = "Buttons", 
  options = list(
    dom = "Bfrtip",
    columnDefs = list(
      list(render = render_js, targets = colIdx + 1 + 1:4), # @Timothy, new
      list(visible = FALSE, targets = ncol(Dat)-1+colIdx),
      list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = colIdx),
      list(className = "dt-center", targets = "_all")
    )
  )
)

path <- "~/Work/R/DT" # folder containing the files dataTables.cellEdit.js
                      # and dataTables.cellEdit.css
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "CellEdit", "1.0.19", path, 
  script = "dataTables.cellEdit.js", stylesheet = "dataTables.cellEdit.css")
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))






library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)

registerInputHandler(
  "nestedData", 
  function(data, ...){
    fromJSON(toJSON(data))
  },
  force = TRUE
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT(dtable)
  
  observe({
    print(input[["data"]])
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: first, my apologies for not adding working reproducible code, that snippet is the latest. However, I see what you're doing here. `input[["data"]]` will be a list that holds the output from `NestedData`. All I will need to do is grab that and format to my liking. Thanks again, you rock!

Comment: @TimothyMcwilliams One problem is that some cell values are converted to `character` when one edits. This is due to the `.toFixed(2)`. And moreover this rounds the result. It would be better to used the `render` option to only *display* the rounded value, without rounding it internally.

Comment: ahh ok, I didn't know that using `.toFixed(2)` converts the data to a `character`. I'll give `render` a look. I am assuming that I just need to wrap that line with `render()`.

Comment: @TimothyMcwilliams No, that does not work in this way. See my edit (second round).

Comment: Gotcha, way different than what I was thinking. Thanks for the edits. All seems to work as expected for the child table. However, `list(render = render_js, targets = colIdx + 1 + 1:4)` is breaking the whole table when applied. `targets` is indexing columns 1 through 4 correct?

Comment: @TimothyMcwilliams Do you encounter this problem when you copy-paste my answer? Or only with your own code?

Comment: I figured it out. I only copied the lines that you changed. I forgot that I added a column to the parent table before posting this. Thats why you were getting errors on that one line. Just had to tweak the `targets` argument

Comment: @TimothyMcwilliams Cool. You also have to remove the `$`s in the cells of the parent table (as  I did). They are set by `render_js`.

Comment: Gotcha, I followed your edits to the T. All is working well. Really appreciate the help on this. That was the hurtle, now that I can access the updated data I can ping that and use it where ever