# R Shiny: how to call a JavaScript function from a custom button inside a Datatable

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, shinyjs

I have downloaded and would like to incorporate in my R Shiny app the following JavaScript library: [GitHub link](https://github.com/calipho-sib/sequence-viewer)

As you can see in the snippet below, I have incorporated the `sequence-viewer.min.js` file in the head of the UI. Additionally, using the `tags$div(id="sequence-viewer")` I am able to see the corresponding `<div>` tag in the source of the web page, so up to this point I think everything is fine.

Using the following code, I construct and render a sample Datatable with sequences. From the link of the last column, I would like to dynamically change the value of the `var seq=new Sequence('');` with the sequences of the Datatable and draw the result in the `sequence-viewer` div every time a link is clicked.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    theme = shinytheme("yeti"),
    useShinyjs(),
    useShinyalert(),
    tags$head(tags$script(src = "handlebars.js"),
              tags$script(src = "sequence-viewer.min.js")),
    mainPanel( DT::dataTableOutput("DTtable"),
               br(),
               tags$div(id="sequence-viewer")
             )
    )

server <- function(input, output) {

exp1 <- reactive({
    tbl <- as.data.frame(c("MALWMPGPGAGSL", "MALKYTFDCVBJUYGFGPGAGSL", "IUYTFVBNMKIUYF"))
    names(tbl) <- "Sequence"
    tbl$link <- createLink(tbl$Sequence)
    return(tbl)
})

createLink <- function(val) {
    link <- paste0("<a href='#' onclick='var seq=new Sequence('",val,"'); seq.render('#sequence-viewer');'>Show seq</a>", sep="")
    return(link)
}

output$DTtable <- DT::renderDataTable({ exp1() 
    }, escape = FALSE, options = list(scrollX = TRUE, dom = 'lfrtip', pageLength = 10, 
lengthMenu=c(10, 25, 50, 100)), rownames = FALSE)

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have read many threads and tutorials on how to run custom `javascript` code in R Shiny, but all the examples that I've found make the call in the `ui` , not in the `server` side, could you please advice me how to get the desired output?

**NOTE:** According to the instructions on github page, the dependencies `jquery`, `handlebars` and `bootstrap.min.css` are required. I suppose that only the `handlebars.js` has to manually be added given that R Shiny comes already with bootstrap and jquery?

**UPDATE 1:** Ok, I think I'm now almost there. Thanks to the comments of @YBS I managed to get the idea of how to work with external javascript libraries. The code below works fine if I click the `actionLink` but it does not work when clicking the custom links inside the Datatable that I create using the `createLink` function. I get the following exception in the console of the browser: *Uncaught ReferenceError: js$seque is not defined*. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jsCode = '
shinyjs.seque = function(params) {
  var defaultParams = {
   seq : "LKJHGFVBJKUGFKGFFGHJKUYTRFGHJUYTGHJIUYT"
 };
 params = shinyjs.getParams(params, defaultParams);

 var seq=new Sequence(params.seq);
 seq.render("#sequence-viewer");
}
'


ui <- fluidPage(
useShinyjs(),
extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("seque")),
tags$head(tags$script(src = "handlebars.js"),
          tags$script(src = "sequence-viewer.min.js")
          ),

mainPanel( DT::dataTableOutput("DTtable"),
           br(),
           actionLink(inputId = "action", 
                        label = "action"),
           br(),
           tags$div(id="sequence-viewer")
    )

 )

server <- function(input, output) {

exp1 <- reactive({
    tbl <- as.data.frame(c("MALWMPGPGAGSL", "MALKYTFDCVBJUYGFGPGAGSL", "IUYTFVBNMKIUYF"))
    names(tbl) <- "Sequence"
    tbl$link <- createLink(tbl$Sequence)
    return(tbl)
})

createLink <- function(val) {
    link <- paste0("<a href='#' onclick='js$seque(",val,")' id='",val,"' class='action-button shiny-bound-input'>Show sequence</a>", sep="")
    return(link)
}

observeEvent(input$action, {
    js$seque("MALKYTFDCVBJUYGFGPGAGSL")
})

output$DTtable <- DT::renderDataTable({ 
    exp1()
}, escape = FALSE, options = list(scrollX = TRUE, dom = 'lfrtip', pageLength = 10, 
                                  lengthMenu=c(10, 25, 50, 100)), rownames = FALSE)

 }

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**UPDATE 2:**

After many hours of debbugging I managed to solve the issue by replacing the `onclick='js$seque(",val,")'` event of the button in the *createLink* function with the following: `onclick='shinyjs.seque(\"",val,"\")'` - or alternatively even clearer `onclick='shinyjs.seque(JSON.stringify(val))'`

In short, the `js$seque` call was incorrect at this point, I had to replace this line with `shinyjs.seque`, namely with the actual name of the function in JS. On the other hand, a typical R `actionButton` element requires `js$seque`. I will try to write a clear MRE code and provide it as an answer of this thread.

Comment: Could you please share any relevant link that I could read more?

Comment: Please take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64159670/replacing-initial-dataframe-from-an-editable-datatable-and-using-that-new-data-f/64161489#64161489, and here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64277527/vertical-alignment-of-numericinput-in-dt/64278584#64278584

Comment: Also, please look at https://deanattali.com/shinyjs/

Comment: Thanks for the links. I think that the first two links are not very relevant to my problem, the third one of @DeanAttali is useful, but all the provided examples (even the advanced) are based on user-defined JS functions, not external JS libraries.

Comment: @YBS please have a look, I have updated my initial question

Comment: Sorry, I am not good in javascript.  That is why I suggested to look at Stephane Laurent and Dean Attali.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of `shinyjs` is an overkill in your case, because you do not want to call the JS function from R but anyways through the client. Thus you can simply use plain JavaScript like in this toy example:

```r
library(shiny)

js <- HTML("seque = function(seq) {
               alert(seq);
           }")

ui <- fluidPage(tags$head(tags$script(js)), 
                tags$a(hreg = "#", onclick = "seque('test message')",
                       "Click me to send test message"))

server <- function(...) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Don't get me wrong `shinyjs`: has its merits, but the typical use case is that you want to trigger JavaScript code from the R side like in this example:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

js_code <- HTML("shinyjs.seque = function(par) {
               var def_par = {seq: 'test message'};
               par = shinyjs.getParams(par, def_par);
               alert(par.seq);
           }")

ui <- fluidPage(useShinyjs(),
                extendShinyjs(text = js_code, functions = "seque"),
                actionButton("click", "Click me to send message"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   observeEvent(input$click,  {
      js$seque("test message from R")
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In this example I use `shinyjs` to call JS directly from R, while in the previous example the JS is called via the `onclick`.

For your example you could use an `actionLink` in your table and add an observer and in this you call `js$queue` but since you will have one link per line this may be tricky (yet not impossible) to code (basically you need dynamic listeners),

Thus, relying on pure JS (`onclick`) as in your example may be the better option, but then you don't need `shinyjs`.